# BizTalk Debatch Input FlatFile with multiple header to multiple file

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-2013, biztalk-2016

I have a requirement where i want to debatch the Below sample file into multiple file without using orchestration ,

Sample

```
H|3|ABC|1|5/10/2023
D|1|543
D|1|543
H|3|ABC|1|5/10/2023
D|1|543
D|1|543
```

The XSD which i have written for the above sample is ,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://FlatFileSchema1" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://FlatFileSchema1" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <schemaEditorExtension:schemaInfo namespaceAlias="b" extensionClass="Microsoft.BizTalk.FlatFileExtension.FlatFileExtension" standardName="Flat File" xmlns:schemaEditorExtension="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/SchemaEditorExtensions" />
      <b:schemaInfo standard="Flat File" codepage="65001" default_pad_char=" " pad_char_type="char" count_positions_by_byte="false" parser_optimization="speed" lookahead_depth="3" suppress_empty_nodes="false" generate_empty_nodes="true" allow_early_termination="false" early_terminate_optional_fields="false" allow_message_breakup_of_infix_root="false" compile_parse_tables="false" root_reference="Root" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0xD 0xA" child_order="postfix" sequence_number="1" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Record">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <recordInfo sequence_number="1" structure="delimited" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0x0D 0x0A" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" child_order="infix" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="Header">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="char" child_delimiter="|" child_order="infix" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" sequence_number="1" tag_name="H" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:annotation>
                      <xs:appinfo>
                        <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                      </xs:appinfo>
                    </xs:annotation>
                    <xs:element name="Root_Child1_Child1" type="xs:string">
                      <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:appinfo>
                          <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="1" />
                        </xs:appinfo>
                      </xs:annotation>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="Root_Child1_Child2" type="xs:string">
                      <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:appinfo>
                          <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="2" />
                        </xs:appinfo>
                      </xs:annotation>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="Root_Child1_Child3" type="xs:string">
                      <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:appinfo>
                          <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="3" />
                        </xs:appinfo>
                      </xs:annotation>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="Root_Child1_Child4" type="xs:string">
                      <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:appinfo>
                          <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="4" />
                        </xs:appinfo>
                      </xs:annotation>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="Root_Child1_Child5" type="xs:string">
                      <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:appinfo>
                          <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="5" />
                        </xs:appinfo>
                      </xs:annotation>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Detail">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="char" child_delimiter="|" child_order="infix" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" sequence_number="2" tag_name="D" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:annotation>
                      <xs:appinfo>
                        <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                      </xs:appinfo>
                    </xs:annotation>
                    <xs:element name="Root_Child2_Child1" type="xs:string">
                      <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:appinfo>
                          <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="1" />
                        </xs:appinfo>
                      </xs:annotation>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="Root_Child2_Child2" type="xs:string">
                      <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:appinfo>
                          <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="2" />
                        </xs:appinfo>
                      </xs:annotation>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="Root_Child2_Child3" type="xs:string">
                      <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:appinfo>
                          <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="3" />
                        </xs:appinfo>
                      </xs:annotation>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The Above schema  is validating with the sample , my requirement is to debatch it in pipeline without using orchestration. When i tested this with the pipeline i am able to get the output not the debatched output. Appreciate any help

Comment: Did my answer below help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a flat file to debatch, you have to create the schema so that only matches the one section you want to debatch on, you have tried to match the whole file.

You need to have the Header and Detail directly under the Root, rather than having a "Record" node under which the Header and Detail are.

[image: Flat File Schema]

And when you test against your example in Visual Studio you should only get one header and two detail lines.

```
<Root xmlns="http://FlatFileSchema1">
    <Header xmlns="">
        <Root_Child1_Child1/>
        <Root_Child1_Child2>3</Root_Child1_Child2>
        <Root_Child1_Child3>ABC</Root_Child1_Child3>
        <Root_Child1_Child4>1</Root_Child1_Child4>
        <Root_Child1_Child5>5/10/2023</Root_Child1_Child5>
    </Header>
    <Detail xmlns="">
        <Root_Child2_Child1/>
        <Root_Child2_Child2>1</Root_Child2_Child2>
        <Root_Child2_Child3>543</Root_Child2_Child3>
    </Detail>
    <Detail xmlns="">
        <Root_Child2_Child1/>
        <Root_Child2_Child2>1</Root_Child2_Child2>
        <Root_Child2_Child3>543</Root_Child2_Child3>
    </Detail>
</Root>
```

So the schema will be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://FlatFileSchema1" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://FlatFileSchema1" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <schemaEditorExtension:schemaInfo namespaceAlias="b" extensionClass="Microsoft.BizTalk.FlatFileExtension.FlatFileExtension" standardName="Flat File" xmlns:schemaEditorExtension="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/SchemaEditorExtensions" />
      <b:schemaInfo standard="Flat File" codepage="65001" default_pad_char=" " pad_char_type="char" count_positions_by_byte="false" parser_optimization="speed" lookahead_depth="3" suppress_empty_nodes="false" generate_empty_nodes="true" allow_early_termination="false" early_terminate_optional_fields="false" allow_message_breakup_of_infix_root="false" compile_parse_tables="false" root_reference="Root" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0xD 0xA" child_order="postfix" sequence_number="1" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:element name="Header">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="char" child_delimiter="|" child_order="infix" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" tag_name="H" sequence_number="1" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="Root_Child1_Child1" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="1" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Root_Child1_Child2" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="2" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Root_Child1_Child3" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="3" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Root_Child1_Child4" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="4" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Root_Child1_Child5" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="5" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Detail">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="char" child_delimiter="|" child_order="infix" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" tag_name="D" sequence_number="2" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="Root_Child2_Child1" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="1" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Root_Child2_Child2" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="2" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Root_Child2_Child3" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="3" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

If you then have that in a Flat File Pipeline, and drop your file through, it will debatch and you will get two messages.